# How to embed an image from Active Storage in Prawn PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn, rails-activestorage

I am trying to embed an image from Rails' [Active Storage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) into a Prawn PDF.

This is what I've got in my Prawn PDF class:

```
path = @view.rails_blob_url(@logo, :host => "localhost:3000", :protocol => "http", :locale => nil)
image(path, :vposition => :center)
```

When I try to open the PDF, I get this error:

> ArgumentError in InvoicesController#show
>   http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBGdz09IiwiZXhwIjxudWxsHCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--06167c36c283f6d5de63ae306b721310af11f70e/Test-Logo.png
>   not found

When I copy that exact same URL into my browser, the image shows up as expected. 5 minutes later it expires (?).

What am I missing here?

How can I show the image in my PDF?

Why can the image be rendered in the browser but not in my PDF?

I've spent all day trying to get this to work today, but to no avail.

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me:

```
def initialize_globals
  logo_from_object = @organization.logo
  @logo = StringIO.open(logo_from_object.download)
  ..
  ..
  ..
end

def print_header
  image @logo, scale: 0.10
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Give this a shot:

```
image ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, @company.logo_image.key), at: [X, Y], width: DESIRED_WIDTH
```

Where `logo_image` is the actual ActiveStorage::Attached::One object.
E.g

```
class Company
  has_one_attached :logo_image
end
```

Also, I believe as of now, only 2 types are supported: png and jpg.

Comment: FWIF this results in `undefined method 'path_for' for #<ActiveStorage::Service::S3Service` in my tries. The answer using `StringIO.open` worked for me.